# How do I get user-mode breakpoints to hit in windbg while kernel debugging?

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, breakpoints, usermode

I'm having trouble getting user mode breakpoints to hit in windbg when I am kernel debugging.  I know that I have to be in the target process's context to set a user mode breakpoint, but that still doesn't seem to work reliably.  Sometimes it works, but I can't wrap my head around what the variable is that is making it work sometimes but not others.  Here is what I am doing.

```
1) !process <process> 0x17, then find a thread that I am curious 
   about.  See that the thread is in mixed user/kernel callstack, 
   identify return address I want to break on.

2) .process /r /p <process>, to change to the target process context

3) .thread <thread>, to change to the thread identified in step (1)

4) bp <addr>, to break on that particular address I care about

5) g
```

Sometimes the breakpoint hits.  Sometimes it doesn't (except I have evidence that the thread has returned).  This makes debugging really frustrating since I never know if things will work.  Thanks for your help.

EDIT: this is not about thread-specific breakpoints, in my example I only change thread to take a callstack, because the callstack shows me the address I need to break on.  In reality I want to break whenever that address is hit.

Answer (score 0):

being in process context helps decipher virtual address.

I  don't  recall being in context guarentees process or thread  specific breaks.

use  bp /p eprocess  address syntax to set process specific breakpoints

although i havent used i recall there are thread specific bps witj bp /t ethread address    refer the docs